# C# USB removal event in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, usb, windows-xp

I am developing a C# class library for a USB-Serial device. I need an event to know when is the USB being removed.

Currently I am using `WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3")` to get notified when the USB is being removed, so that I can disconnect the port after it is unplugged.

This works fine in Windows 7, windows 8 and windows 10.
But in Windows XP SP3, the event does not get triggered when the USB is being removed.
(Remark: My windows XP is installed with .NET 3.5 and .NET 3.5 SP1)

Is there a way I able to get notified when the USB is being removed in Windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN [interval] WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'";
var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcher.Start();
```

Remark: Replace [interval] to specify a polling interval, which you may get more information [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394527(v=vs.85).aspx).